# Rails 3 Carrierwave-Fog-S3 error: Expected(200) <=> Actual(404 Not Found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using Carrerwave 0.5.3 and getting a 404 error on my call to Picture.save in the Create method of my picture controller.  Per the instructions in lib/carrierwave/storage/s3.rb I have the following in my initialization file (config/initializers/carrierwave_fog.rb):

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.s3_access_key_id = "xxxxx"
     config.s3_secret_access_key = "xxxxx"
     config.s3_bucket = "mybucket"  #already created in my S3 account
end
```

In photo_uploader.rb I have:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :s3
  def store_dir
    "uploads"  # already created in my s3 account
  end
  def cache_dir
    "uploads/cache"  #already created in my s3 account
  end
end
```

The exact error:

```
Excon::Errors::NotFound in PicturesController#create
Expected(200) <=> Actual(404 Not Found)
  request => {:expects=>200}
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x00000104a72448 @body="", @headers={}, @status=404>
```

I found a slightly similar question here  [Carrierwave and s3 with heroku error undefined method `fog_credentials='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481523/carrierwave-and-s3-with-heroku-error-undefined-method-fog-credentials) .  But setting things up the way I have it now apparently worked in that case.  Unfortunately it didn't for me.

I've put a picture in my bucket and set the permissions to public and can access the picture via a browser.  So things on the AWS S3 side seem to be working.

Not sure where to go next.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I slept on this for a night came back the next day and all was good.  Not sure why it suddenly started working.

Comment: I faced this error today. It was occurred because of wrong bucket name. Also after fixing the name need to restart the server. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file names are sanitized and do not contain invalid characters like spaces or slashes.
To sanitize a string you can call the `gsub` method on it. The following method call will sanitize files for upload to S3, Google Cloud Storage etc.

```
"Invalid\ file *& | | name.png".gsub(/[^0-9A-z.\-]/, '_')
```